# TeamCity: email notifications to non registered users

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

Is it possible setup TeamCity e-mail notifications to VCS users which doesn't registered in TeamCity?

VCS user name is a first part of e-mail: vasily.pupkin -> vasily.pupkin@company.com

Jenkins has settings for this case: 'Default user e-mail suffix'. May be TC has similar settings?

What I do not want to do:

- force all users to create account
- create all accounts manually as admin
- setup LDAP synchronization now (I need quick, temporary solution)

Comment: We have a related issue in our tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-3737, please vote for it. Current workaround (as described below) is to create a mailing list on your mail server, and register it as additional TeamCity account.

Comment: Thanks. Seems it is OK as temporary solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, you could create a TeamCity user with an email address that is a distribution list. Then you maintain that distribution list outside of TeamCity. In this way you can configure e-mail notifications for this user and it will be sent to the distribution list.

Hope this helps!