# TeamCity Email Notifications

Tags: email, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I want to configure TeamCity to send an email to a couple users - but not all the users of TeamCity. I'm aware that users can individually subscribe to notifications on failure of specific builds, but I'd like to send the email without the users having to subscribe to the build. Is there anyway to do this? The [last update](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-3737) I saw was in 2014.

I know that [sending email to a distribution list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100195/teamcity-email-notifications-to-non-registered-users) is a workaround, but I'd like to know if TeamCity has added support for this since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should be able to create a group, add the users you'd like to receive the email notifications, and configure the appropriate notification rules on the group.  Each of the users should inherit those notification rules.

Answer (score 1):

As of the 2023.05 version of TeamCity, you can configure service messages within a build script using an echo command:

```
echo ##teamcity[notification notifier='email' message='Message body' subject='Email subject' address='user1@gmail.com,user2@yourcompany.com']
```

See more info to configure it in: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html#Canceling+Build+via+Service+Message